# get value of array in ajax, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm using ajax to check validate in client side, but i don't know how to get value in array of ruby on rails. Here is my ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function() {
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var name = $("#username").val();
            var phonenumber = $("#phonenumber").val();
            var pass = $("#password").val();
            var names = $("divname").toString();
            console.log(names);
            ....
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

When i check Console.log, I just see "Object" but not values of array:

```
 "[object Object]"
```

Here is my array, call by ruby on rails:

```
<% @usernames.each do |t| %>
<div id="divname"><%= t.username %></div>
<%end%>
```

Here my coontroller:

```
def index
    @usernames = User.find(:all, :select => "username")
    @user = User.create(:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password],
                        :email => params[:email], :phonenumber => params[:phonenumber])
    if @user 
      render 'index'
    else
      render 'index'
    end
```

So, please! help me to fix that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("divname")` is an jQuery object, so the result of `toString()` is `"[object Object]"`.

**id** should be unique, use `class` instead.

```
<% @usernames.each do |t| %>
  <div class="divname"><%= t.username %></div>
<%end%>
```

Then in js:

```
var names = $(".divname").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(names);
```